# Re-instate old JQuery state

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am re-instating my JQuery to some initial state. Here is my code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link1">link1</a>

<script>
var copiedObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, this); // initial state

$(document).on( "click", "#link1", function() { 
   alert("clicked link 1");
   return false;
});    

Object.keys(this).forEach(function (c) { 
   if(c=='jQuery'||c=='$'){       
      this[c]=copiedObject[c];
   }
});
</script>
```

When I run this, I am still able to run link1. Shouldn't this[jQuery] and this[$] have a copy before I added the binding ? Since copiedObject has a version before I added the click event. I would like to implement this method so I can re-instate bindings from an earlier time. I know I can just use the "off", but there can be more JQuery event bindings in this example and I would simply just like to re-instate the instance before all the bindings are added.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, can you edit it to more clearly state your problem?

Comment: not sure what you are actually trying to do, if you want to remove the binding then use the .off (http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: just use `$(document).off()` and that's it. It'll remove [all handlers that were attached with .on()](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use jQuery's on() function it will add an event handler with JavaScript's native addEventListener if available or attachEvent if not (Internet Explorer 8 and earlier). Those event listeners become part of the DOM object, not of the jQuery state. Therefore your way of trying to remove the event handler by resetting the jQuery state won't work.